I am trying to deploy azure storage account through Azure devOps pipeline (terraform)
I am trying to deploy azure storage account through Azure devOps pipeline (terraform), the configuration is as follows: Storage account, private endpoint with a private service connection for "blob". When i deploy it for the first time it succeeds and created private endpoint successfully with private DNS Zone. Later for the second run with the same configurations i face an error:
Error: retrieving static website properties for Storage Account (Subscription: "qwerty12345"
│ Resource Group Name: "qwerty-01"
│ Storage Account Name: "storage01"): executing request: Get "https://storage01.blob.core.windows.net/?comp=properties&restype=service": dial tcp: lookup storage01.blob.core.windows.net on <ip_address>: no such host
If I delete the previously created storage account and run again it creates the resource successfully. I do not understand why is it giving me an error in the second pipeline run.

The error you're encountering is due to DNS resolution.

The error you're encountering is due to DNS resolution.
When you create a private endpoint for an Azure storage account, the Azure storage account public endpoint (storage01.blob.core.windows.net) is no longer accessible directly; instead, you should be using the private endpoint, which is linked to a private DNS zone.
Make sure that the private DNS zone is properly configured and linked to the virtual network. The DNS settings should resolve storagevehgjgnkat.blob.core.windows.net to the private IP of the private endpoint instead of the public IP.
Once you create a private DNS zone and link it to the VNet, it may take some time for DNS propagation. Wait for a while and then run the second pipeline
Here is the code to create a storage account with a private endpoint, a DNS zone, and a link to the VNet
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  subscription_id = "8332bf56-aa7c-4daa-a507-d7e60e5f09a9"
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "qwerty-01"
  location = "East US"
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = all
  }
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "example-vnet"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
  name                 = "example-subnet"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "storagevehgjgnkat"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier              = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
  is_hns_enabled           = true  # For enabling hierarchical namespace (for ADLS Gen2)
}

resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "example" {
  name                      = "example-private-endpoint"
  location                  = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name       = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  subnet_id                 = azurerm_subnet.example.id
  private_service_connection {
    name                           = "example-blob-connection"
    private_connection_resource_id = azurerm_storage_account.example.id
    is_manual_connection           = false
    subresource_names              = ["blob"]
  }
}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone" "example" {
  name                = "privatelink.blob.core.windows.net"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_a_record" "example" {
  name                = "storage01"
  zone_name           = azurerm_private_dns_zone.example.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  ttl                 = 300
  records             = [azurerm_private_endpoint.example.private_service_connection[0].private_ip_address]
}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link" "example" {
  name                  = "example-vnet-link"
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  private_dns_zone_name = azurerm_private_dns_zone.example.name
  virtual_network_id    = azurerm_virtual_network.example.id
}

output "storage_account_name" {
  value = azurerm_storage_account.example.name
}

DNS records have been created for a private endpoint of the storage account. Once a record is created, it will resolve the storage account via the private IP from the VNet.


It's also worth noting that if you are using a Microsoft-hosted agent on the public internet, you will not be able to interact with that storage account anymore as the storage account is inaccessible. A private agent within a network that has connectivity to your private endpoint will be required. Your answer addresses the Azure side but leaves out an important consideration for the Azure DevOps side.
